# Do I need SS for SPI single-slave communication?

Tags: atmega, spi, pwm

I'm using Atmega328 as a master in SPI communication with a single slave. Is there a way to avoid using the SS (slave select) pin for SPI? That pin can also be used for PWM output, which I would like to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether or not you can tie a SPI slave's "select" input permanently active depends on both the specific slave and the overall system design. Some slaves rely on edges on their select inputs for things like flow control and/or byte alignment.

In some systems, in which the master and slave are always reset together (e.g., via power cycling) and never experience clock glitches, you can get away with it, but it is safer (more reliable) to plan to include an active slave select in your design.

Comment: I would say that in nearly all cases a SS signal is necessary for the slave to function correctly. An exception would be an output shift register (without holding register) that drives something that can tolerate an invalid signal for a short time, like a bar of LEDs. In this case the not-SS signal is more or less implicated in the 'quiet' interval between changing the SR's output. But this is really a borderline case.

Answer (score 4):

ATmega is a master here, as you yourself said.

Let's take a look at what the datasheet says about slave select pin:

`SS: Slave Select input. When the SPI is enabled as a Slave, this pin is configured as an input regardless of the set-
ting of DDB2. As a Slave, the SPI is activated when this pin is driven low. When the SPI is enabled as a Master, the
data direction of this pin is controlled by DDB2. When the pin is forced by the SPI to be an input, the pull-up can still
be controlled by the PORTB2 bit.`

As you can see, it's only used when ATmega is a slave. When it's a master, you use normal GPIO pins to select a slave. There's even a paragraph about that in the datasheet too:

`When configured as a Master, the SPI interface has no automatic control of the SS line. This must be handled by
user software before communication can start.`

<del>In your case, since you only have one slave, you can hard-wire the peripheral's slave select pin to be always selected and not worry any more about it.</del>

In general, active slave select line should be used. Slave select line should activate slave before starting transmission and deactivate it after finishing communication. Any free pin on the ATmega can be used for this purpose.

Comment: What you describe is the ATMega side, but that chip would be equally happy by not driving the clock and data lines! The problem is the slave side: can the slave function without an SS signal?

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I already wrote that slave select pin on the slave can be set up to be always in selected mode and that should work (well unless there's something in the slave that requires the slave select to be pulsed), as far as I know. Do you have any ideas/examples why it wouldn't?

Comment: As far as I know *all* slaves require the SS to be pulsed, expect some borderline cases like the shift-register-with-leds I mentioned in the comment to Dave's answer.

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen I found several tutorials that mention that it's OK so tie the slave select into selected position. Furthermore the SPI Wikipedia article as well as [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/spi.pdf) Microchip document mention that it's OK to leave it hardwired. I also remember that whenever I used SPI, I had hardwired slave select line. I know for sure that such set-up worked fine with MCP3201 ADC, but at the moment I can't remember what other chips I used.

Comment: What I don't dispute is that in general it's good practice to use active slave select and that there are peripherals that requite it to be pulsed. Therefore I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I checked that uChip document and could not find any mentioning of tying SS to a fixed value. The MCP3201 (datasheet p19):"If more cloks are provided to the device while CS is still low (after the LSB-first data has been transmitted), the device will clock out zeros indefinitely." So you need to cycle CS to get a new A/D result. The wikipedia article does not mention any axample - sounds like heresay to me, or maybe it refers to what I call the borderline case of a shift register without output latch.

Answer (score 0):

The term "SPI" is used to describe a wide variety of protocols where a master device communicates with one or more slave devices.  A common scheme is for a slave device to have a "select" line which is asserted at the start of each transaction and released at the end of it.  When using such an approach, the select line serves the dual purpose of synchronizing byte boundaries and also indicating where "commands" start and end.  When communicating with such a slave, it will be necessary to have one of the master's output pins connected to the slave-select wire, but any pin may be used for that purpose.

Some other SPI slaves use different approaches for synchronization.  There's no conceptual reason why slaves should need to use a select wire, but many of them do.  Unless you are designing the slave, the need for the select wire will be determined by the slave itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience on a current project without Slave select pin, you should build ways to verify synchronization/desynchronization between master and slave. Such as: CRC in hardware, Checksum in software, fixed size packets, and add delay between packets so the slave can process the last packet before having data available to the master device. Every time a desynchronization happens slave must reset the SPI machine and waits at least the time between packets to accept data. After these considerations, I would recommend that you don't use SPI without slve select because you are going end up adding too much complexity on something very simple: assigning a GPIO pin on the master as Chip Select.